# Print items from a list in an external .py file

Tags: python, file-io, import, module, python-module

I have a list in a external file and I'm able to access the file but I have a list in that file with the name of `facts`with some items on it but how can I read the items from that list? It goes something like

```
x = open("Trivia"+"/fact.py", "r")
f = x.read()
fact = f.?
```

What do I have to do there? If I run the code like that it just prints the whole list with the variable name and everything.

Comment: Are you trying to treat a Python file as a text file? Because that's what it looks like.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake oh... I didn't know it was meant to be only for text files... It's just that the list is long and I need it to be on another file.

Comment: Assuming that `Trivia/fact.py` is a Python source file which defines a set of facts, you'll probably just want to import it from your script.

Comment: You do know about [modules](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html) right?

Comment: Yes I do know but I'm coming from another language and I'm getting used to this stuff; I'm doing the research about including scripts on my file. @SwiftsNamesake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` is for files containing data; files containing Python code are typically accessed with [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).  See [*The Python Tutorial*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)'s section [6. Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules) for the typical use cases.

Assuming you'll always be running your script from the same directory:

```
import Trivia.fact

do_something_with(Trivia.fact.facts)
```

Or, if you're only going to use that one value:

```
from Trivia.fact import facts

do_something_with(facts)
```

If you want to install all of this as a package so you can run it from anywhere, you will also have to learn about [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages), and maybe the [import path](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-import-path), but don't worry about that until it's clear you need it.

---

All this assumes there's some advantage to storing your data in a Python file --- like it's a list of objects that took a bit of work to initialize.  If it's just "raw" data like strings, then a plain text file with one string per line might be the way to go... and you'd be back to using `open` and probably [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) or `for line in ...:`.

"Nearly-raw" data like tables, dictionaries of numbers and strings, or lists of lists can be read and written with either the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) modules, depending on how complex your data is and which format you're more comfortable with.

Comment: Oooh, I actually got it working. Thank you very much; I didn't know I could import things like that with import.